# how to import project via ankhSVN from visual svn server?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, visualsvn-server, ankhsvn

We are two developers and want to share a project.

On one PC I have VisualSVN server installed (as a SVN server), TortoiseSVN (for adding project to repository), and ankhSVN (for Visual Studio, because it's easier than the others). I can create a repository and add a project to it. On the same PC I can get the project from SVN server using `file://path`. On the other PC I can browse the repository in a browser using `https://PC2/sbn/prj/trunk`, and also with repository browser in VS2010.

But when I want to import the project (file, open, open subversion project), I don't know how to address the URL file, because the https address does not work there.

Is there any special way to address that?

Comment: "because the htpps address does not work there" - do you see any message / error?

Comment: I could finally solve it .
for guys who has a same problem : from repository explorer browse your project and click on check out from svn server , u can get it easily

Comment: @Majidkhalili you can post this as the answer and accept it.

Comment: @bahrep how exactly ?

Comment: @Majidkhalili click Add answer below and tell the solution which worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From repository Explorer select your host , add user and password and login to the server , then find your solution and then click on check out from svn , then you will be able to get the project from svn server .